# Python - Threading - Can I make a list of thread Queues?

Tags: python, multithreading, list, queue

I'm making a threaded chat server and I need a way to send a message to all the clients. I could use a global queue but then only one of the threads handling the clients would be able to send the message. So I was wondering if its possible to create a separate queue object within each of the client threads and append them to a list so that I would be able to send the message to each client's queue. Is this possible?

```
clientqueues = [] #Global list of client queues

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        myqueue = Queue.Queue() #Client queue
        clientqueues.append(myqueue)
        ...
def MessageAllClients(message):
    global clientqueues
    for queue in clientqueues:
        queue.put(message)
```

Would this work or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is just fine. The only thing I would change is making `clientqueues` a [static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506150/static-class-members-python) of `ClientThread` rather than a global variable.

Comment: Well thats great news I'm not thinking crazy after all. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

A Queue is just an object (like everything in Python), so no problem with making a list of them.